# pass answers to popen.subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess, popen

Is there a way to easily pass answers to a executable in python ?

I have a shell install script (third party), it is asking for some parameter before doing install. I'd like to provide that parameter from my python script.

Is something possible ?
like 
    subprocess.popen(myscript,["answer1","answer2"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great Python module that does exactly this, called [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)

Here's an example of using it to run scp interactively (from the pexpect docs):

```
child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo myname@host.example.com:.')
child.expect ('Password:') # wait for 'Password:' to show up
child.sendline (mypassword)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, seems to be able to make indeed what I need, but it seems so huge (and able to make far more as I need), that I'm a bit lost... 
Could you give me  a sample how I just could send a sequence of 2 answers to a script ?

Comment: Great ! And is there a way to only execpt the next question ? 
In my case questions are long, and I'm afraid if a "," change in the question, it won't work anymore... but purhaps I could only expect the end of a question ?

Comment: Just keep using expect() and sendline() as needed. If you look at the docks, I think you can use regular expressions for expect() as well, but I don't recall off hand.

Answer (score 1):

> Is something possible ? like `subprocess.popen(myscript,["answer1","answer2"])`

Yes. If you know all the answers then you could use `Popen.communicate()` to pass the answers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(myscript, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
process.communicate("\n".join(["answer1", "answer2"]))
```

It may fail in some cases and you could use `pexpect` module (as [@Robin Davis suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35173776/4279)), to workaround possible block-buffering issues or issues when input/output is outside of standard streams. See [*Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?*](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)